# Compute Elementary set

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Define f : N×N → N (Zero counted as natural number) by letting f(x,y) = 7x+3y. 
Compute f^-1({16}) and f^-1 ({11})

I understand if f(x)= x^2 for some R you can just go 
f^-1({16}) = {x|f(x) E {16} } 
           = {x|x^2 = 16} = {-4,4}

But what confuses me about my original question is when it has "3y" I don't understand how to move forward with that.

Comment: You need to figure out for what values of $x$ and $y$ you have that $7x+3y=16$. For example, $x=1$ and $y=3$ works. Are there others?  Also, can you get $7x+3y=11$ for any natural numbers $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Bram28 7x+3y = 16 is possible but 7x+3y = 11 is not possible

Comment: Hint: $7x+3y=16 \implies 7x \le 16 \implies x \le \lfloor 16/7 \rfloor = 2\,$. This leaves $3$ potential values for $x$ to try. One of them gives a valid solution for $y\,$.

Comment: @M.Jones Good. So: $f^{-1}(11) = \{ \}$, and we also know that $(1,3) \in f^{-1}(16)$. Are there other natural number solutions to $7x + 3y =16$? If so, add those as well. If not, then $f^{-1}(16) = \{ (1,3) \}$

Comment: @Bram28 thank you totally understand it now !

Comment: @M.Jones You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(16)$ by definition is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N| 7x + 3y = 16\}$

If $7x + 3y = 16$

$6x + 3y + x = 15 + 1$

$2x + y + \frac x3 = 5 + \frac 13$

So $x$ must have a remainder $1$ when divided by $3$.  In other words $x = 3k + 1; k \in \mathbb N$

$2x + y + \frac x3 = 6k + 2 + y + k + \frac 13 = 5 + \frac 13$

$7k + y = 3$

$6k + k + y = 3$

$2k + \frac {k + y}3 = 1$;  So $3$ divides $k+ y$..i.e. $k + y = 3j$ for some natural $j$

So $2k + j = 1$.  There is only one natural solution for that.

$k = 0; j = 1\implies y=3; x = 1$.

So $f^{-1}(16)  = (1,3)$

Notice if we weren't restricted to natural numbers but to any integers then would be infinite solutions:

$2k = 1-j$ implies $j$ is odd.  So $j= 2m+1$ and $k = -m$ and so

$x = 1 + 3k$ for any $k$ and $k+ y = 3(-2k + 1); y = 3-7k $ for the same $k$.